# Humorous synonyms for "lie"

Tags: synonyms

What are some funny synonyms for *to tell a lie*?

E.g. *fib*, *pull a Bill Clinton*, etc.

Comment: Fib isn't funny, and 'pull a Bill Clinton' sounds a bit too partisan and argumentative. Voting to close.

Comment: @Robusto: agreed the examples given aren’t terribly good; but the basic question is just another “big list of slang terms”, and there’s plenty of precedent for this class of question being allowed.  On the other hand, they rarely produce terribly exciting results — I’m not sure how much they add to the site — has there ever been a meta discussion about whether these are on-topic?

Comment: The FAQ reports that a question where every answer is equally valid should not be asked here. If the question would not be subjective (for the fact it asks for _funny synonyms_), then every answer would be equally valid.

Comment: In the UK parliament you aren't allowed to call another politician a liar (!) so the phrase used is "a terminological inexactitude"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Telling **porkies**.  (British & commonwealth slang, from rhyming *pork pies* = *lies*.)
- **Spinning a yarn**.  (Esp. for long, elaborate lies.)
- Being **full of **shit**.  (For a serious but barefaced attempt to pass a lie off as true.  Also with **horseshit**, **bullshit**, or euphemistically just **it**.)
- **Pulling** (someone’s) **leg**.  (Esp. for humorous, inconsequential lies.)
- **Having** (someone) **on**.  (Brit/commonwealth again, I think?  Not to be confused with *having it off*.)

Edit: oh, and how could I forget the classic euphemism:

- Being **economical with the truth**.

Answer (score 3):

I always liked "bamboozle." "Hoodwink" and "hornswoggle" are good too.

Comment: Those are not synonyms of _lie_ but more specific: they're particular ways to lie. (I'm not arguing that this is a bad answer: it's a good one. It just needs a little caveat, as in PLL's and my answers.)

Answer (score 2):

*prevaricate*: to lie.

*tell a tall tale*: relate a story that starts off believably but eventually is obviously false.

*slip one past*: to get away with a (usually small) deceit, often used in the negative: "You nearly slipped that one past me."

*pull the wool over one's eyes*: to successfully deceive someone.

*pull a fast one*: To lie your way out of trouble, generally off-the-cuff, spur-of-the-moment talking.

Comment: But be careful with 'prevaricate': it seems to be in course of changing its meaning to either 'beat around the bush' or 'procrastinate', and will not be understood with its former meaning everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

*Cry wolf* means to raise a false alarm (rather than to lie in general).